# How can I browse Emulator's SDCard?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I'm trying to access the sdcard from my emulator, but it doesn't show any file:
[image]

As you can see, it seems to be empty.

I tried to check if the sdcard was mounted and all, so I put code to show how many MB left are on the sdcard, you can see the debugging, saying that it have 0.24GB free.

Even though i tried to Push a file to the device, it does nothing at all.

What's happening? Do I have to ummount the sdcard from the device?

Comment: What version of Android is your emulator running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this way

go to `mnt/sdcard` this location show your `sdcard`

instead of  `sdcard`

Comment: OMG. I've to shot myself. I've like 10 years experience on all OS environment and theirs Files System and idk what happened to myself, I didn't see that folder. Damn. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

On an Android 4.2 environment, for the initial user account, external storage can be found at `/mnt/shell/emulated/0/`.

Comment: shell folder is empty, but could acces on /mnt/sdcard